como pasar datos de un fichero binario a una estructura con memoria dinamica en C
bueno primero tengo que crear un archivo binario llenandolo de informacion utilizando una estructura, eso ya lo tengo, lo soguiente es recuperar la informacion de ese archivo binario y guardarla en un arreglo del mismo tipo de la estructura esto utilizando memoria dinamica (funcion malloc) dejo codigo de lo que llevo obvio la funcion guardarDeArchivo es la que no funciona mas o menos me doy una idea que asi pueda ir, pero no lo se.
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct disco
{
    char album[100];
    char artista[100];
    int anio;
}Discos;

void llenarArchivo(Discos reg);
void guardarDeArchivo();

int main()
{
    char opcion;
    Discos inf;
    
    do
    {
        printf("\n dame el nombre del album \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(inf.album, 100, stdin);
        
        printf("dame el nombre del artista \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(inf.artista, 100, stdin);
        
        printf("dame el anio del album \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d", &inf.anio);
        
        llenarArchivo(inf);
        
        printf("agregar otro registro s-si  n-no \n");
        scanf(" %c", &opcion);
        
    }while(opcion == 's');
    
    return 0;
}
void llenarArchivo(Discos reg)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    
    fptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\Tony_\\Documentos\\programacion\\registros.bin", "ab");
    
    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("error! \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    fwrite(&reg, sizeof(Discos), 1, fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
}

void guardarDeArchivo()
{
    Discos *registros;
    FILE *fptr;
    if((fptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\Tony_\\Documentos\\programacion\\registros.bin", "rb")) == NULL){
        printf("error abriendo el archivo");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!feof(fptr))
  {
    fread(registros, sizeof(Discos), 1, fptr);
}
}


Yo creo que es mejor nombrar las estructuras en singular. Y tu función no guardaDeArchivo, leeDeArchivo.

El problema es que el puntero no apunta a ninguna parte (o mejor dicho, apunta a un lugar desconocido ya que no está inicializado).
Para reservar memoria usa malloc(bytes). Por ejemplo:
Discos* registros = malloc(cantidad * sizeof(Discos));

Y no te olvides de liberarla con free(registros).
Por cierto fflush(stdin) solo sirve en algunos compiladores. Si necesitas consumir un caracter usa getchar(). O si quieres ignorar espacio en blanco usa scanf(" ").
